# c# integration tests with database transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, integration-testing, localdb

When running c# integration tests, I'm trying to recreate my table in a transaction scope for each test, though I'm getting the following error:

DROP DATABASE statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.

What does it mean? How do I handle it?

Comment: Why would you do a DROP DATABASE if you are only recreating a table?

Comment: I don't know how it works. It throws it when executing: context.Initialize(true)